# PHP: Changing incorrect date format into correct format

Tags: php, date

I have MySQL database with field date format dd/mm/YYYY. As you know this date format is not working perfect with PHP.

How can I transform such (dd/mm/YYYY) into good-looking (YYYY-mm-dd). If there is a PHP function?

Comment: There's plenty of functions in PHP if you look.... personally, I'd recommend [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and then the [format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '25/02/2016');
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can format dates using PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
$date = "2016-03-21";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch date directly from query by using mysql function DATE_FORMAT(date_column,"%d-%m-%Y")

select DATE_FORMAT(date_column,"%d-%m-%Y") as date from table
this will return date in 01-02-2016 format